# Dagger with Conductor Controllers

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger, conductor

I am experimenting with the '*new*' Android support in Dagger 2.
I want to set up the following architecture in Dagger:

> Application => Activity => Controller ([Conductor](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor))

*(Controller is basically a `View` that gets instantiated by the system. You can think of it like `Fragment`s but without Dagger Injection support)*

For each level I have defined a dependency: `ApplicationDep`, `ActivityDep` and `ControllerDep`.

1. My `Controller` should be able to inject all of these dependencies.
2. My `Activity` should be able to inject the `ApplicationDep` and the `ActivityDep`
3. My `Application` should only be able to inject the `ApplicationDep`

Everything works except in my `Controller`.
I am unable to inject the `ActivityDep`.

```
public class MyController extends Controller {
  @Inject
  ApplicationDependency applicationDependency;
  //@Inject
  //ActivityDependency activityDependency; // can not be provided
  @Inject
  ControllerDependency controllerDependency;

  @NonNull @Override protected View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater layoutInflater, @NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ConductorInjection.inject(this);
    return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.controller_main, viewGroup, false);
  }
}
```

Currently I have my `ControllerBindingModule` bound on my `ApplicationComponent`, however this should be bound on the `Activity` in order for it to be also available in the `Controller`.
How can I do this?

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        ApplicationModule.class,
        ActivityBindingModule.class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,

        ConductorInjectionModule.class,
        ControllerBindingModule.class
})
interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<App> {
    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<App> {}
}
```

The full code can be found on [Github](https://github.com/timrijckaert/conductor-dagger).
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like controller is a subcomponent of activity component.
I took a look at your GitHub, so I change some of your code to answer.

First, for the `Activity` injection.
`Controller` is not subcomponent of `Appcomponent`, so it only need `ActivityBindingModule`.

**AppComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AppModule.class
        ActivityBindingModule.class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
})
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<App> {}
}
```

For the same reason, we only need to implement `HasActivityInjector` in `App`.

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {
    @Inject protected DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingActivityInjector;

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingActivityInjector;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .create(this)
            .inject(this);
    }
}
```

Because I need to declare `Controller` as subcomponent of `ActivityComponent`,
I use step 2 & step 3 in [Dagger documentation about injecting activity objects](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html#injecting-activity-objects.)

Change your `ActivityBindingModule`

**ActivityBindingModule.java**

```
@Module(subcomponents = {MainActivityComponent.class})
public abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(MainActivity.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity>
    bindYourActivityInjectorFactory(MainActivityComponent.Builder builder);
}
```

Create an `ActivityComponent`.

**MainActivityComponent.java**

```
@Subcomponent(modules = {MainActivityModule.class})
@ActivityScope
public interface MainActivityComponent extends AndroidInjector<MainActivity>{
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity> {}
}
```

Next, it time to set controller as a subcomponent of activitycomponent.
Add `ControllerBindingModule.class` to `MainActivityComponent`.

```
@Subcomponent(modules = {MainActivityModule.class, ControllerBindingModule.class})
@ActivityScope
public interface MainActivityComponent extends AndroidInjector<MainActivity>{
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity> {}
}
```

And implement `HasControllerInjector` in `MainActivity`.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HasControllerInjector {

    @Inject protected DispatchingAndroidInjector<Controller> dispatchingControllerInjector;

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Controller> controllerInjector() {
        return dispatchingControllerInjector;
}
```

No need to change other files, and what you want is done.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However just a few questions. 
Howcome you don't need to include the `ConductorInjectionModule.class`anywhere?
And is it possible to have my Application to implement the `HasControllerInjector`? 
Could you elaborate your answer, it would help me to understand? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the first question, I really have no idea. For the second question, an object bound in a subcomponent can depend on any object that is bound in its parent component or any ancestor component. If you implement HasControllerInjector in Application, you can only use member in Applicationmodule and Controllermodule.

Comment: Would you mind that I ask your first question to a new question post? I found that it may work even I don't use AndroidSupportInjectionModule.

Comment: Warning! You will leak actvity if you add activity dependencies in your controller and doesn't unbind those dependencies when activity is destroyed. I would recommand to make controller component a sub component of app component instead. App -> Activity -> controller hierarchy just looks wrong, controller is not a fragment.

Comment: You can check my demo project: https://github.com/hijamoya/Android-Kotlin-Dagger2-Conductor-Example